# Need help defining 5x5 custom aruco dictionary with border width of 2

Tags: opencv, augmented-reality, aruco

I'm attempting to do **ar marker detection** in Python. I got my algorithm to work based on the predefined dictionaries in **aruco**.

However, the markers I really need to detect have a **border width** of `2` instead of `1`. I was wondering what the easiest method of detecting these types of tags would be. I've attempted the `Dictionary_create()` and `custom_dictionary()` in Python functions to no avail.